# Angular throwing exception 'module cant be loaded'!

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I was trying to clean my angular app code up. So I moved all the controllers in their own files. But when I moved the controllers, my main app stoped working and started throwing the exception below -

> Error: $injector:modulerr
>   Module Error

Then I tried searching for the why the module won't load but with no luck.

```
main.js /*File where app module is declared*/

var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','thatisuday.dropzone','UserController','LinkController','articleController']);
```

I tried injecting the dependency for the controller files.

Controllers:

Link Controller

```
var app = angular.module('app');

app.controller('LinkController', ['$scope','$http','$sce',function ($scope, $http, $sce) {
/*Sce declaration required for proxy settings*/
$scope.renderHtml = function (html_code) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
};

$scope.trustSrc = function (src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
};

/*First AJAX request which gets all the links and categories for the user*/

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/users'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {

    $scope.user = response.data;

}, function errorCallback(response) {

});

$scope.getUser = function () {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/users'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

        $scope.user = response.data;

    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });
};


$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/links'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {

    this.orderProp = 'age';

    /*the response is saved in scope variables*/
    $scope.links = response.data[0];
    $scope.categories = response.data[1];
    $scope.categorytolink = response.data[2];


}, function errorCallback(response) {
    console.log('There was a problem! Refresh!');
});

/*AJAX request for getting the recommendations according to the most viewed stars*/

$http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: '/recommendations/top'
}).then(function successCallback(response) {

    $scope.recommendations = response.data;

}, function errorCallback(response) {

});

/*AJAX request when a user clicks a link retrieves the link data*/
$scope.getLinkData = function (link) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: "/proxy",
        headers: {
            "X-Proxy-To": link.rss_link
        }
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

        /*AJAX request: add a star to the link*/

        $http.post('/links/' + link.id + '/views/add', {'link': link}).then(function successCallback(data, status, headers, config) {

            // Manually increment star for link just clicked

            var $data;

            $data = data.data;

            $scope.link = $data;

            console.log('200 OK! Star added');

        }, function errorCallback() {

            console.log('Error!');

        });

        /*The data will be retrieved and will be sorted according to the requirements of welcome.blade*/

        $myXml = response.data;

        $xmlObj = $.parseXML($myXml);

        $newsItems = [];

        $channelImage = $($xmlObj).find("channel>image");

        /*the information of the link is sorted */

        $linkData = {
            "title": $channelImage.find("title").text(),
            "link": $channelImage.find("link").text(),
            "imgurl": $channelImage.find("url").text()

        };

        /*the data is sorted below*/

        $.each($($xmlObj).find("item"), function (index, value) {
            $newsItems.push({
                "title": $(value).find("title").text(),
                "description": $(value).find("description").text(),
                "link": $(value).find("link").text(),
                "date_published": moment($(value).find("pubDate").text()).format('MMMM Do YYYY'),
                "time_published": moment($(value).find("pubDate").text()).format('h:mm:ss a'),
                "guid": $(value).find("guid").text()
            })
        });

        $scope.newsItems = $newsItems;

        $scope.linkData = $linkData;

    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });
};


/*Create a category private to the user*/

$scope.create_category = function (category) {

    /*AJAX request: adds a new category*/
    $http.post('/categories/new', {'category': category}).then(function successCallback(response) {

        /*AJAX request: Updates the categories for the use of new category*/

        $http({
            method: 'GET',
            url: '/categories'
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {

            $scope.categories = response.data;

        }, function errorCallback(response) {

        });
    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });

};
}]);
```

User Controller

```
    var app = angular.module('app');

app.controller("UserController", ['$scope','$http','$sce', function ($scope, $http, $sce) {

/*Sce declaration required for proxy settings*/
$scope.renderHtml = function (html_code) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
};

$scope.trustSrc = function (src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
};

$scope.dzOptions = {
    paramName: "file",
    dictDefaultMessage: "<h4><i class='fa fa-camera'></i> <b>Upload</b></h4>",
    createImageThumbnails: false,
    autoDiscover: false
};

$scope.dzCallbacks = {
    'sending': function (file, xhr, formData) {
        formData.append('_token', $('#csrf-token').val());
    },
    'success': function (file, response) {
        $scope.user = response;
        $.notify("Profile photo changed!", "success", {autoHide: true, autoHideDelay: 500});
    }
};

/*Update user info*/
$scope.updateUser = function () {
    /*AJAX request: update user info*/
    $http.post('/users/update', {
        'name': $scope.user.name,
        'username': $scope.user.username,
        'email': $scope.user.email
    }).then(
        function successCallback(data) {
            $scope.user = data;
            $.notify("User updated!", "success", {autoHide: true, autoHideDelay: 500});
            console.log('200 OK! User updated');
        }, function errorCallback() {
            console.log('Error!');
        });
};

}]);
```

Article Controller

```
    var app = angular.module('app');

app.controller("articleController", ['$scope','$http','$sce', function ($scope, $http, $sce) {

/*Sce declaration required for proxy settings*/
$scope.renderHtml = function (html_code) {
    return $sce.trustAsHtml(html_code);
};

$scope.trustSrc = function (src) {
    return $sce.trustAsResourceUrl(src);
};

/*Populates the comments for particular
 * */
$scope.populatecomments = function (newsItem) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/articles/' + newsItem.guid + '/comments'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

        $scope.comments = response.data;

    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });
};

$scope.data = [];
$scope.comment = [];
$scope.btn_add = function (newsItem) {
    if ($scope.txtcomment != '') {
        $scope.data.push({
            "comment": $scope.txtcomment,
            "guid": newsItem.guid
        });
        $http.post('/comments/new', {
            "comment": $scope.txtcomment,
            "guid": newsItem.guid
        }).then(function successCallback() {

            var encodedURI = encodeURIComponent(newsItem.guid);

            $http({
                method: 'GET',
                url: '/articles/' + encodedURI + '/comments'
            }).then(function successCallback(response) {

                $scope.comments = response.data;

                $scope.txtcomment = "";

            }, function errorCallback(response) {

            });
        }, function errorCallback() {

            console.log('Error comment!');
        });

    }
};

$scope.savearticle = function (newsItem) {
    $http.post('/saved-articles/save', newsItem).then(function successCallback(response) {
        /*console.log(document.getElementById("save/"+newsItem.guid).className="disabled");*/
    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });
}

/**
 * The saved articles by the user will be retrieved when a button clicked
 */

$scope.getSavedArticles = function () {

    /*AJAX request: retreive the saved the saved articles for the user*/

    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '/saved-articles'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {

        $scope.linkData = null;

        $scope.newsItems = response.data;


    }, function errorCallback(response) {

    });
};
}]);
```

HELP needed!

Answer (score 1):

Yo do not need to declare module in each controller file. Remove the line in each controller

```
 var app = angular.module('app');
```

Answer (score 0):

You are injecting controller in you module like dependency.

Change your main.js file to this:

```
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','thatisuday.dropzone']);
```

@Sajeetharan is right you do not need module declaration in all controllers.

Since you are using laravel according to your comment. ( It will conflict with your blade template because both use same {{ }} for variables )

*There are two ways to do this:*

**Change the Angular Tags**

```
var app = angular.module('app', [], function($interpolateProvider) {
        $interpolateProvider.startSymbol('<%');
        $interpolateProvider.endSymbol('%>');
    });
```

> Now Laravel will use the {{ variableName }} and Angular will use <%
>   variableName %>.

**Change the Laravel Blade Tags**

```
 Blade::setContentTags('<%', '%>');// for variables and all things Blade
 Blade::setEscapedContentTags('<%%', '%%>');// for escaped data
```

> Variables will be: <% $variable %>. Comments will be: <%-- $variable
>   --%>. Escaped data will look like: <%% $variable %%>.

You can check this [Tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/quick-tip-using-laravel-blade-with-angularjs) for more info.

Comment: I tried deleting the all the injections. And also deleted the duplicate module definitions for my module. Didn't work it is still throwing the module not loaded exception.

Comment: did you removed ngRoute,thatisuday.dropzone also? share you html structure also!

Comment: No I didn't remove the 'ngRoute' and ,thatisuday.dropzone. var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','thatisuday.dropzone']);

Comment: have you added script for these dependency? and have you defined your ng-app in body or in relevent html element?

Comment: Added the html in the answers.

Comment: there are a lot of errors in you html you are using comment structure ({{ --comment-- }}  which is used by angular experession and i think you have not provided scripts for ngRoute,thatisuday.dropzone dependencies.

Comment: I am using laravel framework and have integrated angular and laravel. Some of the html in will be laravel variables. So the html will throw lot of errors. I also am using node and composer to install certain packages as 'thatisuday.dropzone'.